# How to set the values of private members using public property?

Tags: c#

This is my class:

```
 class EmpDetails
    {
        private string _EmpName;
        private int _EmpID;
        private string _EmpDepartment;
        private string _EmpPosition;

        public string EmpName
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmpName;
            }
            set
            {
                _EmpName = value;
            }
        }
        public int EmpID
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmpID;
            }
            set
            {
                _EmpID = value;
            }

        }
        public string EmpDepartment
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmpDepartment;
            }
            set
            {
                _EmpDepartment = value;
            }
        }
        public string EmpPosition
        {
            get
            {
                return _EmpPosition;
            }
            set
            {
                _EmpPosition = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        EmpDetails d = new EmpDetails();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            d.EmpName = txtName.Text;
            d.EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);
            d.EmpDepartment = txtDepartment.Text;
            d.EmpPosition = txtPosition.Text;
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Clear();
            txtID.Clear();
            txtDepartment.Clear();
            txtPosition.Clear();
        }

        private void btnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtName.Text = d.EmpName;
            txtID.Text = Convert.ToString(d.EmpID);
            txtDepartment.Text = d.EmpDepartment;
            txtPosition.Text = d.EmpPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

I am setting the values using text boxes in form so that the values go
in to properties I have created in class.

I'm getting error like:   `EncapsulationAssignmentCSharp.EmpDetails`
does not contain a  definition for `GetEmpName` and no extension
method `GetEmpName`  accepting a first argument of type 
`EncapsulationAssignmentCSharp.EmpDetails` could be found (are you 
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I am guessing that I have to create a constructor with parameters and
set the values using keyword `this`, but I'm not sure how to pass the
values to the constructor. Please help me I am not very good with
programming.

Comment: The code is fine. Sounds like there is a missing using directive somwewhere, as the error suggests. Are the form and class in the same namespace? What line is this occuring on?

Comment: I can't see code where `GetEmpName` is called? Are you sure, that compiler error results from that code?

Comment: This is not a home work. I created a project name that way so I can remember. I have other projects too in my projects folder.

Comment: Yes they are under same name space. It says Line 22 and column 52

Comment: Have you declared your class as `public`?

Comment: No the class is created by default like: class EmpDetails

Comment: I figured out the error. Now its working fine. Anyway, thanks for your response Arran.

Comment: I don't know how to close the question :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug and run the code and check whether your code is calling GetEmpName